# error on adding custom framework in Xcode

Tags: iphone, cocoa

i am getting the error....

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FaceBook", referenced from:
ld: symbol(s) not found collect2: 
ld returned 1 exit status**
```

when i am trying to use a class from my custom framework.
the name of class is FaceBook in this case.

Can anyone please suggest me some idea how to do fix this problem.

Comment: when you're saying framework do you mean a static library?

Answer (score 2):

There's no way how to use dynamically linked custom frameworks in iOS application. If you do want to use custom framework, you have to compile it and use it as a static library (physically linked with your application, IOW is distributed with your application).

Then you have to set your project dependencies, header paths and you also have to link your static library to your iOS application. This can be done in this way ...

Xcode [REDACTED] - Project Settings - select your Target - switch to Build Phases - expand Link Binary With Libraries - add you static library here and mark it as required.

Xcode 3.x - here's an example how to do it http://wiki.remobjects.com/wiki/Linking_Custom_Static_Libraries_from_your_iPhone_Xcode_Projects

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the target you are running has included the Facebook files.